# Rails PaperTrail versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the Paper Trail gem to version one of my models.

It works very nicely, I refined when it logs versions so that it tracks updates on approved products only, this part works fine.

What I also need to do is capture the version on approval. Naturally, on approval my approved field is set to false so it doesn't capture the version. Does anyone know how I can modify the line in my product model below to achieve this?

```
has_paper_trail :on => [:update,:approve], :if => Proc.new { |p| p.approved == true }
```

EDIT: It seems papertrail doesn't work on custom controller actions. Can anyone verify that?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb#L65` it only works with the three default events being `create, update, destroy`. A possible workaround would be to fire the `update` event in your `approve` method, which you might already be doing.

```
# in your model
def approve!
  self.approved = true
  save
end
```

Comment: I know it's probably not best practise, but my approval is handled within my controller with `@product.approved = true @product.save`. However, am I right in thinking `@product.save` should be firing the update?

Comment: Yap, it should fire - i guess `label_approved` and `p.approved` are actually the same in your code ? Otherwise this might not work as expected

Comment: Ah, yes same thing! Edited above now. The approve action does update the approved field correctly, but I guess has_paper_trail is working on before_update rather than after, which makes sense if it's recording a version before changes are made.